# Spring jpa @OneToMany one direction always null

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "member")
public class MemberEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "memberId")
    private List<PhoneEntity> phoneEntities;
}


@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "phone")
public class PhoneEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column
    private Integer memberId;
}


@Repository
public interface MemberRepository extends JpaRepository<MemberEntity, Integer> {

    @Query("select m from MemberEntity m join fetch m.phoneEntities where m.id=?1")
    MemberEntity findByIdWithPhone(Integer id);
}
```

create OneToMany relationship from `Member` to `Phone`

im trying to select `Member` fetch join with `Phone` using `@Query("select m from MemberEntity m join fetch m.phoneEntities where m.id=?1")`
 Query

this query created like under my-sql query

```
SELECT 
memberenti0_.id as id1_0_0_,
phoneentit1_.id as id1_1_1_,
phoneentit1_.member_id as member_i2_1_1_,
phoneentit1_.member_id as member_i2_1_0__,
phoneentit1_.id as id1_1_0__ 
from member memberenti0_
inner join phone phoneentit1_ on memberenti0_.id=phoneentit1_.member_id
where memberenti0_.id=?
```

and result `MemberEntity` is not null(this mean insert and inner join is work!) but `MemberEntity#phoneEntities` is always null

im trying to change `List<PhoneEntity>` `Collections<PhoneEntity>` `Set<PhoneEntity>` all collection type doesn't work.

I doubt column in Phone table call twice in the generated query(member_i2_1_1_, member_i2_1_0__), but I do not know why.

Comment: So you do call ` MemberEntity#getPhoneEntities()` and get null???

Comment: Also `member_id` is not mapped to `memberId` in `PhoneEntity`

Comment: yes that method return null.

Comment: So you call it on detach entity.

Comment: How can it be that you have specified `@JoinColumn(name = "memberId")` but the SQL uses a column `phoneentit1_.member_id`? How can this query even execute never mind return the wrong data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to correct your mapping as:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "member")
public class MemberEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @OneToMany(
        mappedBy = "member"
    )        
    private List<PhoneEntity> phoneEntities;
}


@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "phone")
public class PhoneEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY) // Or Eager 
    @JoinColumn(name = "member_id")
    private MemberEntity member;
}
```

And there no need to specify join in the query :

```
@Query("select m from MemberEntity m where m.id=?1")
```

Comment: there is no way without relationship in `PhoneEntity`?

Comment: A Unidirectional relationship is perfectly valid and I don't see that this is the cause of your problem.